# Basic FTC question

Tags: calculus

I was working through some Fundamental Theorem of Calc questions on Brilliant and I had some trouble with the following:

"Given

$$f(x)=\int_3^{x^2}\frac {\sqrt {1+t^6}} tdt$$

$$F(x)=\int_3^xf(t)dt$$

what is the value of $F''(2)$?"

According to Brilliant, the answer is $\sqrt {4097}$, but I don't understand why... I think the $x^2$ is throwing me off in the top part of the equation.

My reasoning: I know that $F'(x)=f(x)$ because of FTC I. So to find $F''(x)$, all I need to do now is figure out what $f'(x)$ is. I was thinking I could just reapply FTC I to $f(x)$ and substitute $x^2$ for $t$, and then I get $f'(x)=\frac {\sqrt {1+{(x^2)}^6}} {x^2} = \frac {\sqrt {1+x^{12}}} {x^2}=\frac {\sqrt {4097}} {4}$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To evaluate $f'(x)$, we need to use the Chain Rule. By the FTC, the derivative with respect to $u$ of 
$$\int_3^u g(t)\,dt$$ is 
$g(u)$. It follows that the derivative with respect to $x$ of 
$$\int_3^{x^2}g(t)\,dt$$ is $(2x)g(x^2)$.